# ArcGIS Pro how to make legend layer label text be on one line

Tags: arcgis-pro

I want to disable word wrapping but I find no option to. I have made the legend box as wide as it should be. When the label text font size is small, it is on one line, but when I increase the font size then it wraps into 2 lines despite there being space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [ESRI help page](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/layouts/work-with-a-legend.htm)

> 1. In the Contents pane, right-click the legend and click Properties
>    to open the Element pane. Be sure to click the legend
>    element, not a legend item. Legend items have different properties.
> 2. In the Element pane, select the tab containing the properties you
>    want to change.
>
>    - Options tab Options :Turn on or off the legend title, and adjust the title text.
>    - Legend Arrangement Options tab : Set fitting strategy, word wrapping, and spacing properties.
>    - Display tab : Set border, background, and shadow properties.
>    - Placement tab : Set size, position, and rotation properties for the entire legend.
> 3. Adjust the properties as desired.

As you see the word wrapping setting is in the Legend Arrangement Options tab (it's the second icon with two arrow and two small square), make sure to set a value appropriate for your text length here.

Answer (score 0):

In the content pane on the left side, right click on the legend and click "Convert to Graphics". This will give you more fine grained control over how the legend looks. This fixed my issue and made the layer label one line again. Here is a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dpALcT9TWwc) for a better explanation: